# div on change doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening!

I have the following code in jQuery that doesnt work. The idea of the code is to fade in or fade out the div depending on the contents.

html code:

```
<div class="mainContentWrapper">
    sample text
</div>
```

css code:

```
div.mainContentWrapper{
display: none;
width: 80%;
margin: 0.5% 10%;
padding: 0.5% 3%;
box-sizing: border-box;

border-radius: 4px;
border: 0.15em solid #1C86EE;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
}
```

jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mainContentWrapper').on('change',function(){
    var mainContentWrapper_str=$.trim($(this).text());
    if(mainContentWrapper_str.length==0){
        $('.mainContentWrapper').fadeOut(500);
    }else{
        $('.mainContentWrapper').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: And what is `.mainContentWrapper`? You have to post the HTML as well!

Comment: What event are you trying to listen to? As DerRoteBaron stated, there is no `'change'` event to listen to on a `div`. If you have code that is modifying the content of `.mainContentWrapper`, you would want to put the fade code after that code executes.

Comment: How exactly would the contents of a DIV change ?

Comment: i was going to use jQuery's ajax

Comment: Then why not execute the functionality in `onchange` handler in  AJAX's success function?

Answer (score 3):

`onChange` dosen't apply to changes to the css. It is meant for user interface elements such as `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 1):

onChange can only be used with `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`.